# I made a Mac OSX app from .jar. Does end-user need Java?

Tags: java, macos, executable

I had a jar file that opened a calculator. I turned into a .app on my macintosh using a tool called [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice). My app works fine on my computer but I am wondering if the app will work on a the end-user who does not have Java? I would test this myself but I do not have access to a computer with Java uninstalled. Thanks ahead oft time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can package Oracle's JRE within your app.  Apple will even accept it into the AppStore.

The tool is called appbundler.  This is the guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

A fork of appbundler which adds some features can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler

Answer (score 2):

You are at a very tricky spot mate!

Firstly thankfully you can port jre along with your application (oracle java gives you the [license](http://You%20are%20at%20a%20very%20tricky%20spot%20mate!%20%20Firstly%20thankfully%20you%20can%20port%20jre%20along%20with%20your%20application%20(oracle%20java%20gives%20you%20the%20license).%20The%20tricky%20part%20is%20building%20the%20dmg%20for%20your%20application.%20i.e.%20not%20only%20one%20has%20to%20port%20jre%20along,%20but%20also%20build%20it%20in%20such%20a%20manner%20that%20works%20like%20any%20other%20mac%20application.%20Including%20the%20permissions.%20Trust%20me,%20its%20quite%20tough%20to%20get%20it%20right.%20%20So%20here%20are%20the%20options:%20%20Go%20the%20Javafx%20way.%20Javafx%20has%20native%20support%20to%20build%20dmg%20files%20easily.%20This%20is%20especially%20nice%20because%20javafx%20ant%20has%20tasks%20that%20let%20you%20build%20dmg%20as%20part%20of%20its%20build%20system.%20Read%20this%20to%20know%20more.%20You%20can%20set%20icon,%20any%20system%20dependencies%20you%20want%20(dll%20or%20so).%20Set%20system%20properties%20etc.%20Definitely%20lets%20you%20feel%20very%20native.%20Other%20non-professional%20but%20a%20working%20way.%20Ask%20the%20user%20to%20download%20java.%20You%20can%20provide%20a%20simple%20application%20which%20shows%20a%20pop-up%20asking%20user%20to%20download.%20Once%20he%20does,%20he%20can%20then%20double-click%20the%20jar%20to%20make%20it%20run.%20I%20would%20go%20via%20javafx%20way.%20We%20have%20two%20desktop%20applications%20in%20production%20for%20windows%20and%20mac%20and%20we%20build%20it%20via%20the%20first%20way)). The tricky part is building the `dmg` for your application. i.e. not only one has to port jre along, but also build it in such a manner that works like any other mac application. Including the permissions. Trust me, its quite tough to get it right.

So here are the options:

- Go the Javafx way. Javafx has native support to build dmg files easily. This is especially nice because javafx ant has tasks that let you build dmg as part of its build system. Read this to know [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm). You can set icon, carry any system dependencies you want (`dll` or `so`). Set system properties etc. Definitely lets you feel very native.
- Other non-professional but a working way. Ask the user to download java. You can provide a simple application which shows a pop-up asking user to download. Once he does, he can then double-click the jar to make it run.

I would go via javafx way. We have two desktop applications in production for windows and mac and we build it via the first way

Comment: Is Javafx a library that I have to make my GUI in before I deliver it. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Yes. It is a replacement of swing. GUI toolkit. In case you dont have a gui, another hack is: To make a javafx application but do not have any UI. i.e. let there be no UI and do your task. This way you can use javafx ant and hence generate the build.

Comment: Or if your application is a swing application, make a javafx application with invisible UI. And then launch your swing application. This way you dont have to re-engineer your code. But yes the build tool will change. Thats why I said, its tricky to get it right. Do let me know, in case you come across a better method

Comment: The [Java packaging tools which ship with Oracle Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html#CCHIHIIJ) can package a Java application that makes no use of JavaFX.  The tools are not JavaFX specific.  You can package your existing Swing or SWT based Java application as a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI) without turning it into a JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. End use will need Java on their machine.

Comment: Do you know of any way that I can make it so they don't need Java?

Comment: Short of bundling a Java runtime environment within an installation package  for your app I don't see how you could do it.

Comment: And I am guessing that bundling JRE will make the app size huge?

Comment: Much bigger yes.  Huge means different things to different people though.

Comment: @ikhaliq15 Huge is a relative term, it will definitely make the app bigger. However, if you start distributing the JRE, you need to think about licensing as well.

Comment: @blm is correct about licensing.  Not sure if you are allowed to redis Oracle's JVM.  OpenJDK jvm is possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you use amipackage.
It packages the jre too...

Here are the steps....

```
a) Download amipackage
b) Setup a config file that describes your app
c) ./amipackage.sh --config=<your config file>
d) your dmg and tar.gz are present in the out folder.
```

I found it very simple

https://www.amidb.com/amipackage/index.html

Comment: @bummi - What i posted does solve the problem.  We all work to sell software. Please do not be rude. It is worse that what you think is spamming. Having your profile point to external sites does not help either.